# Content type disappears in content list

Tags: nodes

I created a taxonomy with the same name as a content type. Now the list shows with no content type on the nodes with that type. I have since renamed the taxonomy, but there is still an issue.

When trying to edit the node from the admin menu I get the following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: case_studies_node_form in drupal_retrieve_form() (line 750 of C:\wamp\www\ppi\includes\form.inc).
>
> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'case_studies_node_form' not found or invalid function name in drupal_retrieve_form() (line 785 of C:\wamp\www\ppi\includes\form.inc).

I checked the database and the nodes have the correct type in the content table, and the content types table still has the "Case Studies" type.

Comment: Two things to try: 1. Clear your caches. 2. Maybe [this](http://drupal.org/node/1094238) link is relevant?

Comment: I have cleared my caches for sure. This link came up in my search, but I cannot even get to anything to change in the Drupal admin section. I am going to try altering the machine name in the database (after a backup, of course).

Comment: did you create this content type programmatically or via the admin UI? Drupal 6 or 7?

Comment: When you changed the taxonomy name, have you changed the machine name too?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

1. Make sure the module handling custom node type exists and is enabled.

   Based on `case_studies_node_form` callback, it's most likely `case_studies` module.

   If you don't know type of the node, you can load it using `drush`, e.g.

   ```
   drush ev "var_dump(node_load(123));"
   ```
2. Make sure the module which handles custom node type defines [`hook_node_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_info/7.x) in its `.module` file.
3. Clear caches (`drush cc all`, restart Memcached/Redis if present).